# Prove that $n^k < 2^n$ for all large enough $n$

Tags: inequality

If $k\ge 2$ is an integer,
prove by elementary means
(no calculus or limits)
that
there is a $N(k)$
such that
$n^k < 2^n$
for all integers $n \ge N(k)$.
Give an explicit form for $N(k)$.

Comment: Three votes to close *as off topic*??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By Bernoulli

$$\sqrt[2k]{2}^n \geq 1+n(\sqrt[2k]{2}-1) \,.$$

Pick an $N(K)$ so that

$$\sqrt{N(K)}(\sqrt[2k]{2}-1) > 1 \,.(*)$$

Then, for all  $n > N(K)$ we have

$$\sqrt[2k]{2}^n \geq 1+n(\sqrt[2k]{2}-1) > \sqrt{n}\sqrt{N(K)}(\sqrt[2k]{2}-1) > \sqrt{n} \,.$$

The value we get for $N(K)$ from $(*)$ is:

$$N(K)=1+\left\lfloor \left(  \frac{1}{\sqrt[2k]{2}-1} \right)^2  \right\rfloor $$

Comment: I think the first inequality goes the other way: Bernoulli says that $(1+x)^n \ge 1+nx$.

Comment: @martycohen Yes, that's exactly what I wrote: $\sqrt[2k]{2}^n =(1+\sqrt[2k]{2}-1)^n  \geq 1+n(\sqrt[2k]{2}-1)$. Or, $x= (\sqrt[2k]{2}-1)$.

Comment: I see. Also, shouldn't the expression for $N(K)$ be squared, since (*) has $\sqrt{N(K)}$? Also$^2$, could you write a simpler expression for $N(K)$?

Comment: @martycohen Ty, fixed that.

Answer (score 7):

Note that a polynomial with positive leading coefficient is eventually positive: If $$p(x)=a_0+\dots+a_nx^n$$ and $a_n>0$, then $p(x)>0$ for $x$ large enough. For example, we can write $p(x)=a_n[(c_0+\dots+c_{n-1}x^{n-1})+x^n]$, and note that
 $$ |c_0+\dots+c_{n-1}x^{n-1}|\le |c_0|+\dots+|c_{n-1}|x^{n-1}\le x^n/2 $$
as long as $K:=\max\{1,2n|c_i|\colon i<n\}<x$, so $\displaystyle |c_i|<\frac{x}{2n}$ for all $i$, and $x^k<x^n$ for all $k<n$. This means that 
 $$ |p(x)|\ge a_n(x^n-|c_0+\dots+c_{n-1}x^{n-1}|)\ge a_n(x^n-x^n/2)>0, $$
the inequality holding at least for $x>K$.

Now, for $n>0$, we have that $\displaystyle 2^n\ge\binom n{k+1}$ (since the left hand side counts all subsets of a set of $n$ elements, and the right hand side only counts those subsets of size exactly $k+1$), and the latter is a polynomial of degree $k+1$ and positive leading coefficient. This means (by the previous paragraph) that $\displaystyle \binom n{k+1}>n^k$ for $n$ large enough, as $\displaystyle \binom n{k+1}-n^k$ is a polynomial with positive leading coefficient. But then $2^n>n^k$, as we wanted.

The value of $K$ can be computed directly from the expansion of $\displaystyle \binom n{k+1}-n^k$.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant, the binomial coefficient, $\binom n{k+1}=\frac{n(n-1)\dots(n-k)}{(k+1)!}$, seen as a polynomial in $n$.

Comment: Doesn't "eventually positive" part have something to do with limits?

Comment: I'll accept this if you give an explicit formula for $K$.

Comment: We have $\binom n{k+1}-n^k=\sum_{i=0}^{k+1}a_i x^i$. Here, $a_{k+1}=1/(k+1)!$, and in general $a_i=s(k+1,i)/(k+1)!$, where the $s(k+1,i)$ are the [Stirling numbers of the first kind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_first_kind), except for $a_k=s(k+1,k)/(k+1)! - 1$. Letting $c_i=s(k+1,i)$, except for $c_k=s(k+1,i)-(k+1)!$, we can take $K=\max\{1,2(k+1)|c_i|\colon i<k+1\}$. I expect this bound can be significantly lowered, though.

Comment: The asymptotic growth of the Stirling numbers is a delicate topic, but some details are [here](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0607514.pdf).

Answer (score 4):

Write the inequality as
$n < 2^{n/k}$.

Suppose this is true for $n$.
I want to find conditions such that
this is also true for $n+1$.

By assumption,
$n+1 
= n(1+\frac1{n})
< 2^{n/k}(1+\frac1{n})
$
and this is
less than
$2^{(n+1)/k}$
if
$2^{n/k}(1+\frac1{n})
< 2^{(n+1)/k}$
or
$2^{1/k} > 1+\frac1{n}$.

I showed in another solution
(from $(1+\frac{x}{k})^k < \frac1{1-x}$
for $0 < x < 1$,with $x = \frac12$)
 that
$2^{1/k} > 1+\frac1{2k}$,
so, if $n \ge 2k$
and
$2^n > n^k$,
then
$2^m > m^k$ for
all $m \ge n$.

We now need to find an initial $n \ge 2k$
such that $2^n > n^k$.

Let's try $n = ak$ for some $a$.
$2^{ak} > (ak)^k
\iff 2^a > ak
$.
Almost, but not quite.

Let's try $n = k^2$.
$2^{k^2} > (k^2)^k
\iff 2^{k} > k^2
$.
This is easy by induction.
$2^5 > 5^2$,
and, if $2^k > k^2$ and $k \ge 5$,
$$(k+1)^2 = k^2+2k+1
= k^2(1+\frac{2}{k}+\frac1{k^2})
< 2^k(1+\frac{2}{5}+\frac1{25})
< 2^k(2)
= 2^{k+1}
$$

So, by this nested induction,
if $k \ge 5$,
if $n \ge k^2$
(so that, certainly, $n \ge 2k$),
$2^n > n^k$.

For $k = 2, 3,$ and $4$,
respective values of
$n \ge 2k$ such that
$2^n > n^k$ are
$5$ ($2^5 > 5^2$),
$10$ ($2^{10} > 10^3$),
and
$17$ ($2^{17} = 131072> 17^4=83521$).

These values of $n$ happen to be
$k^2+1$,
so the final result is:

If $n$ and $k$ are integers
and $k \ge 2$
and
$n \ge k^2+1$,
then
$2^n > n^k$.

Answer (score 2):

Pick $n > 2k$. Then, 
$$
2^n > \binom{n}{k + 1} = \frac{n (n - 1) \cdot \ldots \cdot (n - k)}{(k+1)!}
\geq \frac{n^{k + 1}}{2^{k+1} (k+1)!}
$$ 
by a trivial combinatorial argument for the first inequality, and using $n - k > n/2$ in the second inequality.
Therefore $2^n > n^k$ as soon as
$$
n > 2^{k + 1} (k + 1)!
$$

Comment: I'll accept it, even though your bound is quite large.

Comment: It's possible to improve it significantly! I'll post a comment later.