# Prove $2^n > n^3$ for all $n \ge10$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, induction

I am stuck with the this question:

> Prove by induction that $2^n > n^3$, for all $n \ge 10$

I got this far:

Base: For $P(10)$:
$$
2^n > n^3 \\
2^{10} > 10^3 \\
1024 > 1000 
$$
so, $P(10)$ is true

Inductive steps: Need to show $P(k+1)$ is true, assuming $P(k)$ is true.

For $P(k+1)$:
$$
2^{k+1} > (k+1)^3 \\
2 \times 2^k > k^3 + 3k^2 + 3k + 1 \\
2^k + 2^k > k^3 + 3k^2 + 3k + 1 
$$

We assume $2^k > k^3$, so we only need to show $2^k > 3k^2 + 3k + 1$ ?
But I am stuck here.

Any idea/hints?
Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: You know that $2^k>k^3$; can you prove that $k^3\ge 3k^2+3k+1$?

Comment: @vadim123 no, not really :(

Comment: @amWhy thanks for pointing out the duplicate

Comment: You're welcome, @user350954!

Comment: [Related](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/439026/462).

Answer (score 1):

Since $k\ge10$, $(1+1/k)^3=((1+1/k)^k)^{3/k}\le (e)^{1/3}\lt2$.
Hence, if $2^k\gt k^3$, then $2^{k+1}\gt2k^3\gt k^3(1+1/k)^3=(k+1)^3$.
So the proof is complete.

Comment: I did not find that there was a duplicate...

Comment: thanks for the answer but I haven't learned e, so I cannot follow your thought

Comment: The last solution in the linked problem has a similar character, since it uses ratios.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Yes, I guess that answer is essentially the same as mine, while not availing of the definition of $e$.

Comment: @user350954 Maybe you can try to prove that $\lim_{k\to\infty}(1+1/k)^k$ exists, and that this limit is less than $8$! I think this is contained in every calculus text. If necessary, I can do it, I think. :)