# Solving inequality having log

Tags: inequality, logarithms

I am struggling to solve this inequality involving logarithm.
How to find out values of $n$ for which below inequality holds good:

$${\log_2n \over n} >{ 1 \over 8}$$

Answer (score 1):

Rearrange this to state that

$$\log{n} > \frac{n}{8}$$

since clearly $n > 0$. Exponentiate and find that

$$n > 2^{n/8}$$

or alternatively,

$$n^8 > 2^n$$

This can be solved exactly using the Lambert W function, or done numerically to find that the upper bound is about $43.56$ as [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2%5En+-+n%5E8+%3D+0) or [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+2%5En+-+n%5E8+between+43+and+44).

Comment: Thanks Bongers. I have to learn about the W function now :)

Answer (score 0):

I proved a more general result 
as an answer to a similar question:

If $n$ and $k$ are integers
and $k \ge 2$
and
$n \ge k^2+1$,
then
$2^n > n^k$.

For $k=8$ this gives
$65$ which is not too far from
the best bound of
$43.56$.

The proof is here:
[Prove that $n^k < 2^n$ for all large enough $n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/439026/prove-that-nk-2n-for-all-large-enough-n/439027#439027)