# Showing $\sum^\infty_{n=1} \frac 1 {e^{\sqrt n}} $ converges

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, proof-verification

> Show that $\displaystyle\sum^\infty_{n=1} \frac 1 {e^{\sqrt n}}$ converges.

My attempt:

Using limit ratio test: $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac {e^{\sqrt n}} {e^{\sqrt {n+1}}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac {e^{\frac n 2}} {e^{\frac {n+1} 2}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac {e^{\frac n 2}} {e^{\frac n 2+\frac 1 2}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac 1 {e^{\frac n 2+\frac 1 2-\frac n 2}}=e^{-0.5}$

And since $e^{-0.5}<1$ the series converges.

Is that alright?

Comment: In the first equality, are you saying that
$$
e^{\sqrt n} = e^{n/2}?
$$
If so then no, your proof is not correct.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom uh why that's not correct?

Comment: $e^{\sqrt n} \neq \sqrt{e^n}$.  If we had the latter expression, we **could** say that
$$
\sqrt{e^n} = (e^n)^{1/2} = e^{n/2}
$$

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The correct application of the ratio test would be as follows:
$$
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac {e^{\sqrt n}} {e^{\sqrt {n+1}}}&=
\lim_{n \to \infty} e^{\sqrt n - \sqrt{n+1}} 
\\ & =
\exp\left[ \lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt n - \sqrt{n + 1} \right]
\\ & =
\exp \left[ \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{-1}{\sqrt n + \sqrt{n + 1}} \right] = 1
\end{align*}
$$
So, the ratio test fails.  In fact, we could use the comparison test with, for example, $\sum 1/n^2$.  It suffices to note that
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1/e^{\sqrt n}}{1/n^2} = 0
$$
To prove the above, we have
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1/e^{\sqrt n}}{1/n^2} = 
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n^2}{e^{\sqrt n}} \overset{u = \sqrt n}{=} 
\lim_{u \to \infty} \frac{(u^2)^2}{e^u} = 
\lim_{u \to \infty} \frac{u^4}{e^u}
$$
from there, apply L'Hospital's rule.

Answer (score 3):

The condensation test
works here:
if $f(n)$
is positive and decreasing,
then
$\sum f(n)$
converges if and only if
$\sum 2^n f(2^n)$
converges.

If 
$f(n) = e^{-\sqrt{n}}$,
then
$2^n f(n) 
= 2^n e^{-\sqrt{2^n}}
= e^{n \ln 2 -2^{n/2}}
$.
Since
$2^n > n^4$
for $n \ge 17$
(see a proof 
in my answer here:
[Prove that $n^k < 2^n$ for all large enough $n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/439026/prove-that-nk-2n-for-all-large-enough-n)),
$ 2^{n/2}
> n^2
$
so
$e^{n \ln 2 -2^{n/2}}
<e^{n \ln 2 -n^2}
<e^{-n(n- \ln 2)}
$
and the sum of these
clearly converges.

Note:
The result I proved there is this:

If $n$ and $k$ are integers and $k≥2$ and $n≥k^2+1$, then $2^n>n^k$.

Answer (score 3):

$$
\begin{split}
\displaystyle\sum^\infty_{n=1} \frac 1 {e^{\sqrt n}}&=\ 
\underbrace{e^{-\sqrt1}+e^{-\sqrt2}+e^{-\sqrt3}}_{3\text{ terms}}
+
\underbrace{e^{-\sqrt4}+e^{-\sqrt5}+e^{-\sqrt6}+e^{-\sqrt7}+e^{-\sqrt8}}_{5\text{ terms}}
+
\underbrace{e^{-\sqrt9}+\cdots + e^{-\sqrt{15}}}_{7\text{ terms}}
+
\cdots\\
&<\ 3\cdot e^{-\sqrt1}+5\cdot e^{-\sqrt4}+7\cdot e^{-\sqrt9}+\cdots+(2k+1)\cdot e^{-\sqrt{k^2}}+\cdots\\
&=\ 3\cdot e^{-1}+5\cdot e^{-2}+7\cdot e^{-3}+\cdots+(2k+1)\cdot e^{-k}+\cdots\\
&<\ 4\cdot e^{-1}+8\cdot e^{-2}+16\cdot e^{-3}+\cdots2^{k+1}\cdot e^{-k}+\cdots\\
&=\ \frac{4\cdot e^{-1}}{1-\frac{2}{e}}<\infty.
\end{split}
$$

Comment: Why is it equal to: $\frac{4\cdot e^{-1}}{1-\frac{2}{e}}$?

Comment: The last step uses the formula for the sum of an infinite geometric series: $a+ar+ar^2+\cdots=\frac{a}{1-r}$. The series here has first term $4e^{-1}$ and common ratio $\frac{2}{e}$ (which has absolute value less than $1$, as required by the formula).

Answer (score 2):

The step

> $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac {e^{\sqrt n}} {e^{\sqrt {n+1}}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac {e^{\frac n 2}} {e^{\frac {n+1} 2}}$$

desperately needs justification.

Since $$\frac {e^{\sqrt n}} {e^{\sqrt {n+1}}} = e^{\sqrt{n} - \sqrt{n+1}}$$ and $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left( \sqrt{n} - \sqrt{n+1} \right) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{-1}{\sqrt{n} + \sqrt{n+1}} = 0$$
you actually have $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{e^{\sqrt n}} {e^{\sqrt {n+1}}} = 1.$$

Comment: I love the "desperately".

Answer (score 2):

A very simple answer
just occurred to me.

For
$\sum^\infty_{n=1} \frac 1 {e^{\sqrt n}}
$,
by looking at the
first few terms of the
power series,
$e^{\sqrt n}
\gt 1+\sqrt n
+\frac{(\sqrt n)^2}{2}
+\frac{(\sqrt n)^3}{6}
\gt\frac{(\sqrt n)^3}{6}
=\frac{n^{3/2}}{6}
$
so that
$\sum^N_{n=1} \frac 1 {e^{\sqrt n}}
\lt \sum^N_{n=1} \frac 6 {n^{3/2}}
$
which converges by the comparison test.

Note that this method
can show that
$\sum^N_{n=1} \frac 1 {e^{n^a}}
$
converges
for any $a > 0$
by going far enough out
in the power series:
$e^{n^a}
\gt \frac{(n^a)^m}{m!}
= \frac{n^{am}}{m!}
$,
so if we choose
$m \gt \frac1{a}$,
this shows that
the series converges.

Comment: What's stopping you from the taking the remainder like this for any series?

Comment: What remainder?

Comment: I meant the smaller part of the series, the value before the actual remainder.

Comment: Nothing. The exponential series has the nice property that all its coefficients are positive, so any particular one can be chosen. For alternating series, like for $e^{-x}, \sin(x), \cos(x)$, this does not work.