# The order statistics of uniform distribution $U_{n,k_n}\rightarrow p$ a.s., when $\frac{K_n}{n} \rightarrow p$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution, probability-limit-theorems

Let $U_1,U_2,...U_n,$ be iid samples from uniform distribution $U(0,1)$. And the order Statistic:
\begin{equation}
U_{n,1}\leq U_{n,2}\leq ...\leq U_{n,n},
\end{equation}

Given $p\in(0,1)$, if $1\leq K_n\leq n$ and $\frac{K_n}{n}\rightarrow p$. Proof $U_{n,k_n}\rightarrow p$ a.s.

My ideas so far:

The density function of $U_{n,k_n}$ is
\begin{equation}
f_n(x)=\frac{n!}{(k_n-1)!(n-k_n)!}x^{k_n-1}(1-x)^{n-k_n}.
\end{equation}
Then I would like to proof:
\begin{equation}
\sum_n P(|U_{n,k_n}-p|>\epsilon)<\infty
\end{equation}
Then by Borel-Cantelli lemma:
\begin{equation}
P(|U_{n,k_n}-p|>\epsilon \quad\text{i.o.})=0
\end{equation}
which means:
\begin{equation}
U_{n,k_n}\rightarrow p = 0. \quad a.s.
\end{equation}
However, the integral of $P(|U_{n,k_n}-p|>\epsilon)<\infty$ is hard to calculate. Do I miss something? Does there exist some easy way to proof this?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Notice that the density you quote is the density of a certain Beta distribution. To find your required bound, it may be fruitful to look up concentration inequalities for Beta distributions.

Comment: Where is this exercise from ? A textbook ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\mu_n:=\mathsf{E}U_{n,k_n}$. Using an exponential bound found [here](https://books.google.nl/books?id=st7TBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA84&dq=reiss+Exponential+Bounds+for+Order+Statistics+of+Uniform+R.V.%27s&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjLuoLX_Oj2AhXNvKQKHSrLCIwQ6AF6BAgFEAI#v=onepage&q=reiss%20Exponential%20Bounds%20for%20Order%20Statistics%20of%20Uniform%20R.V.%27s&f=false), i.e.,
$$
\mathsf{P}(|U_{n,k_n}-\mu_n|>\epsilon)\le 2\exp(-\sqrt{n}\epsilon/(5\sigma_n)),
$$
where $\sigma_n:=\mu_n(1-\mu_n)$, one gets
$$
\sum_{n\ge 1}\mathsf{P}(|U_{n,k_n}-p|>\epsilon)\le \sum_{n\ge 1}2\exp(-\sqrt{n}\epsilon/(10\sigma_n))+1\{|\mu_n-p|>\epsilon/2\}<\infty
$$
because $\mu_n\to p$. (See also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1174116/showing-sum-infty-n-1-frac-1-e-sqrt-n-converges) regarding series convergence.)