# Clarification about this post: The order statistics of uniform distribution $U_{n,k_n}→p$ a.s., when $K_n/n→p$

Tags: order-statistics

Could anyone elaborate a bit on the question of this post or provide a reference for it: [The order statistics of uniform distribution $U_{n,k_n}\rightarrow p$ a.s., when $\frac{K_n}{n} \rightarrow p$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4414426/the-order-statistics-of-uniform-distribution-u-n-k-n-rightarrow-p-a-s-when)

Does it mean we randomly select $k_n$ according to a distribution and $U_{n,k_n}$ converged to the mean of that distribution? @Knotnet