# How do you prove that $4^n > n^3$ for all positive integers $n$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-verification, induction

Prove that $4^n > n^3$ for every positive integer $n$ using the Principle of Mathematical Induction.

I am well aware of how to use this proof technique. I first showed that P(1) is true: $4^1 > 1^3$. Then I made the assumption that $4^k > k^3$ for an arbitrary positive integer $k$. Thus the goal is to show that $4^{k+1} > (k+1)^3$. So I tried changing the expression to $4^k \times 4 > (k+1)^3$. This is where I am stuck.

Answer (score 2):

**Note:** Here is an easy way of going about it: Let $S(n)$ denote the proposition that
$$
S(n) : 4^n > n^3
$$
for all $n\geq 1$. We have that $S(1)$ is true because $4^1=4>1=1^3$. Also, we have that $S(2)$ is true because $4^2=16>8=2^3$ (these are the **base cases**). Thus, let's prove $S(n)$ to be true for all $n\geq 2$ (the reason for this will become clear in a moment).

**Inductive step:** Fix some $k\geq 2$ and assume that
$$
S(k) : 4^k > k^3
$$
holds. To be shown is that 
$$
S(k+1) : 4^{k+1} > (k+1)^3
$$
follows. Starting with the left-hand side of $S(k+1)$,
\begin{align}
4^{k+1} &= 4\cdot 4^k\tag{by definition}\\[0.5em]
&> 4\cdot k^3\tag{by $S(k)$}\\[0.5em]
&> (k+1)^3,\tag{since $k\geq 2$; see $(\dagger)$ for reason}
\end{align}
we end up at the right-hand side of $S(k+1)$. This concludes the inductive step.

By mathematical induction, we see that $S(n)$ holds for all $n\geq 2$. Also, since the base case held for $n=1$, we know that $S(n)$ holds for all $n\geq 1$.

---

$(\dagger)$: Note that
$$
(k+1)^3 = k^3+3k^2+3k+1,
$$
and
$$
4k^3 > k^3+3k^2+3k+1 \Longleftrightarrow 3k^3-3k^2-3k>1 \Longleftrightarrow \underbrace{3k(k^2-k-1)>1}_{\text{true if $k\;\geq\;2$}}.
$$
Does it make sense now?

Comment: Can you show that $3k(k^2-k-1)>1$ is true for $k\;\geq\;2$.

Comment: @john $f$ is concave up for $f_1(k) = k^2-k-1$ and increasing over $k\geq\frac{1}{2}$. The minimum of $f_1$ for $k\geq 2$ is $f_1(2)=1$. And the minimum for $f_2(k)=3k$ for $k\geq 2$ is $f_2(2)=6$. What are we left to conclude?

Answer (score 1):

Which is bigger, $4$ or $(\frac{k+1}{k})^3$?

$1.5^3=3.375$

Well, $4^{k+1}=4^k\cdot 4>k^3\cdot 4>k^3\cdot (\frac{k+1}{k})^3=(k+1)^3$. This is no longer a hint now.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to extend your base case to examine $n=2$ explicitly as well, and then consider that for $k\ge 2$, moving from $k^3$ to $(k+1)^3$ will involve multiplying by a number no bigger than $\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^3 = \frac{27}{8}<4$

Answer (score 1):

$4^{k+1}=4\cdot 4^k > 4\cdot k^3 > (k+1)^3$ since
$$\left(\frac{k+1}{k}\right)^3=\left(1+\frac{1}{k}\right)^3\leq\left(1+\frac{1}{2}\right)^3=(1.5)^3=3.375<4$$
(See eccstarup's answer).

Answer (score 1):

To see if $4^n>n^3$ for all $n>1$, first establish bench marks.

For $n=1$, we see that $4^1=4>1^3=1$ checks.  For $n=2$, we see that $4^2=16>2^3=8$ checks.

Now, assume that the inequality is true for some $k>2$.  Then, $4^k>k^3$.  Let's test to see if $4^{k+1}>(k+1)^3$.

$4^{k+1}=4(4^k)>4(k^3)$

Now, compare $4(k^3)$ to $(k+1)^3$.  This is equivalent to comparing $4$ to $(1+k^{-1})^3$.  But for $k>2$, $(1+k^{-1})^3\le (\frac43)^3=\frac{64}{27}<4$!  And that is that.

Answer (score 1):

In case you don't want 
to use induction:

I proved
(using induction twice)
 that
if $n$ and $k$ are integers
and $k \ge 2$
and
$n \ge k^2+1$,
then
$2^n > n^k$
here:
[Prove that $n^k < 2^n$ for all large enough $n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/439026/prove-that-nk-2n-for-all-large-enough-n)

Putting $k=2$,
$n^2 < 2^n$ for
$n \ge 5$,
so,
squaring,
$4^n > n^4
> n^3$
for $n \ge 5$.

For completion,
examine the smaller $n$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:-**

Instead of proving the inequality directly apply induction to the statement that, $$P(k):\sqrt[3]{4}-1>\dfrac{1}{k}$$

---

If you are interested in other methods then,

- Let $u_n=\dfrac{4^n}{n^3}$. Then, $$\dfrac{u_{n+1}}{u_n}=\dfrac{4}{\left(1+\dfrac{1}{n}\right)^3}$$Now note that $n\ge\left\lceil\dfrac{1}{\sqrt[3]{4}-1}\right\rceil\implies 4>\left(1+\dfrac{1}{n}\right)^3$.
- Alternatively you can examine the behavior of the function $f(x)=4^x-x^3$ and note that since $f$ is increasing it is sufficient to find the value of $x$ at which $f>0$.