# Is there any proposition provable by induction whose evaluation oscillates for small numbers and is true for all large enough numbers?

Tags: induction

Actually, I want a proposition $P(n)$ defined over the natural numbers such that:

1. $P(a)$ is true.
2. $P(b)$ is false.
3. $P(c)$ is true.
4. $a<b<c$.
5. $P(n)$ is true for all $n \geq n_0$.
6. We can prove (5) by induction.

In other words, I want a proposition whose evaluation **oscillates** for small numbers, and then is true for all sufficiently large numbers.

Is there such thing?

Comment: $n-1000$ is either not even or not negative.

Comment: Is this true for all large enough $n$?

Comment: The edited comment is, I don't know if that's the one you're looking at. It was wrong at first.

Comment: Oh sorry, I saw the first version of the comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$2^n \ge n^2$ is true at $0$,  true at $1$, true at $2$, false at $3$, true at $4$, and then true forever. One can prove by induction that it is true for all $n\ge 4$.

Comment: Can you find me another one, where this $n=3$ is larger? Something like, $P(n)$ is true for $n=1,2,...,49$, false for $n=50$, and true for all $n > 50$. Not necessarily for $n=50$, but a big number...

Comment: @matheuscscp You just said it yourself.  $P_k(n) = (1 \le n \le k-1 \text{ or } k+1 \le n) $

Comment: I need some proposition where this "failure value" is "hidden", you know? Something you'd be surprised when you find out. This one is too much obvious...

Comment: And something we could use algebraic manipulation to prove the induction step.

Comment: I  will try to think of something that qualifies. The induction step in the above example does require some (mild) algebraic manipulation.

Comment: @matheuscscp: Is the example in my answer sufficiently not obvious? I'm not sure why you'd like to find such things anyway, unless you're looking for possible induction questions for students!

Answer (score 2):

$$
P(n)=\begin{cases}
\text{FALSE}, & n\equiv 0\pmod 2 \text{ and } n<n_0\\
\text{TRUE}, & n\equiv 1\pmod 2 \text{ and } n<n_0\\
\text{TRUE}, & \text{ Otherwise. }
\end{cases}
$$

If you don't want it in functional notation, consider this:

Let $Q(n)$ mean "$n$ is in the set $T$", where $T=\{n\in\Bbb N : P(n)\}$.

Answer (score 1):

"If $P(n)$ is the $n$th prime then $P(n)\geq 2 n.$"... TRUE for $n=1$. FALSE for $n=2,3,4$. TRUE for $n=5$. For $n\geq 5,$ if $P(n)\geq 2 n$ then $P(n+1)\geq P(n)+2\geq 2 n+2=2(n+1).$ So,by induction on $n$ (for $n\geq 5)$, TRUE for all $ n\geq 5.$

Comment: Can you find me another one, where this $n=3$ is larger? Something like, $P(n)$ is true for $n=1,2,...,49$, false for $n=50$, and true for all $n > 50$. Not necessarily for $n=50$, but a big number...

Comment: A journalist once asked Prof.Leo Morse if he could name a property that was true only for numbers less than a  million. Answer:  Yes.  Question:  What  property?  Answer :  Being less than a million...... (And  BTW $ n\geq 1000000\to n+1\geq 1000000$ for the induction.)

Comment: There is a compendium of sequences of natural numbers. I don't recall its acronym or its name. Perhaps someone else can help. You might find some interesting examples in it.

Comment: I came across the name of the site of the compendium of sequences It is OEIS.ORG

Answer (score 1):

Show that,
for fixed $k$,
$2^n > n^k$
for large enough $n$
and find a value for $n$
as a function of $k$.

In my answer,
I showed that
if $k > 2$
and $n > k^2+1$
then
$2^n > n^k$.
For large $k$
and small $n$,
$2^n \le n^k$,
so this is an infinite class
of problems
of the type you seek.

[Prove that $n^k < 2^n$ for all large enough $n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/439026/prove-that-nk-2n-for-all-large-enough-n)

Answer (score 1):

Here's one with tuneable parameters (and a fairly natural problem, as well):

"For positive coprime $a$ and $b$, every number greater than $ab - a - b$ can represented as a sum of a non-negative multiple of $a$ and a non-negative multiple of $b$".

Half the numbers (i.e.: $(a-1)(b-1)/2$) below the boundary can be represented as such.

For example, every number larger than 41 can be written as a sum of a positive multiple of 7 and a positive multiple of 8, and 21 of the numbers between 0 and 41 inclusive can't be written like that.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coin_problem for more about this.

Answer (score 0):

**Fickle predicate that is eventually always true**

Let $P(n)$ be "$n$ is either odd or the product of two distinct numbers more than $1$.".

The sequence of truth-values of $P$ on $1,2,3,...$ is:

> $1,0,1,0,1,1,1,...$

It can of course be proven by induction that $P(n)$ is true for every integer $n > 4$.

**Predicate that alternates for a long time**

Just for fun, here is a predicate that alternates for $9$ terms before breaking the pattern on the $10$-th. However, it does not have the required property of being true of sufficiently large positive integers.

Let $Q(n)$ be "The minimum number of unit-length matchsticks needed to form $n$ unit equilateral triangles is either $2$ or $3$ more than a multiple of $4$.".

The sequence of minimum number of matchsticks needed is:

> $3,5,7,9,11,12,14,16,18,19,21,23,24,...$

The sequence of truth-values of $P$ on $1,2,3,...$ is:

> $1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,...$

Answer (score 0):

$(-1)^n + \frac{n}{C} \ge 0$ holds for positive even integer $n$ or integer $n \ge C$. That is, the truth of the inequality oscillates until $n = C$.

Proof:

1. Assume $(-1)^n + \frac{n}{C} \ge 0$, then
   $(-1)^{(n+2)} + \frac{n+2}{C} = (-1)^n (-1)^2 + \frac{n}{C} + \frac{2}{C} = (-1)^n + \frac{n}{C} + \frac{2}{C} \ge (-1)^n + \frac{n}{C} \ge 0$.
   So if true for any integer, it is also true for every second higher integer.
2. For $n = 0$ it gives: $(-1)^0 + \frac{0}{C} = 1 \ge 0$ and is true, thus it holds for every even integer.
3. For $C$ uneven: $n = C$ gives:  $(-1)^C + \frac{C}{C} = -1 +1 \ge 0$ is true. Now it holds for all integers $n \ge C$
4. For $C$ even: $n = C + 1$ gives:  $(-1)^{(C+1)} + \frac{C+1}{C} = -1 +1+\frac{1}{C} \ge 0$  is true. Now it holds for all integers $n \ge C$
5. QED

You can choose $C > 0$ to fit your needs. You can even choose non-integer $C$, this will slightly change the proof by change of $C$ with ceil(C) in step 3 or 4. ($C = e^\pi$, is more "hidden" than 50.)