# Prove the following: For n ≥ 4, n ^2 ≤ 2^n

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing, induction, proof-explanation

I have been asked to prove the following:

For n ≥ 4, n$^2$ ≤ 2$^n$

I will argue by induction the statement *P(k): for n ≥ 4, n$^2$ ≤ 2$^n$*.

First, consider the base case *P(4) = 16 ≤ 16* which is true, so we assume *P(n)* holds and consider *P(n+1)*.

*2$^{n+1}$ = 2$^n$2*

We know that *2$^n$2 ≥ 2$^n$* and from our induction hypothesis we also know that *n$^2$ ≤ 2$^n$*, so we know that *2$^n$2 ≥ 2$^n$ ≥ n$^2$*.

This is the part that makes me a bit uncomfortable and I think is wrong:

*(n+1)$^2$ ≥ 2$^n$* by our induction hypothesis and definition of inequality.

Then, also by definition of inequality:

*2$^n$2 ≥ (n+1)$^2$ ≥ 2$^n$ ≥ n$^2$*

Thus, we have completed our induction step and shown that *2$^{n+1}$ ≥ (n+1)$^2$*.

I am worried about my jump that *(n+1)$^2$ ≥ 2$^n$*. Do I need to some kind of subproof here to prove this relation? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: $2^n2 \neq 4^n$.

Comment: Ahh, that's an embarrassing mistake that I have corrected. Thanks :)

Comment: What is your induction hypothesis?

Comment: My induction hypothesis is just that for n ≥ 4, n^2 ≤ 2^n

Comment: Going back to your proof, what do you mean by $2^n2\geq 2^{n*}$

Comment: Oops! That was the result of some shoddy html on my part. Just fixed. :)

Comment: Remember that our objective is to show that $$2^{n+1}\geq (n+1)^2.$$ In your proof, you did it correctly that $$2^{n+1}\geq n^2.$$  What is next then? So, to attain the objective, you need to show that $$n^2\geq (n+1)^2$$ and use transitive property. But the latter inequality is false. Hope this help. That is why, I present to you my answer which I think the logical one.

Comment: One thing more I noticed in your proof and I quote."Then, also by definition of inequality:

*2$^n$2 ≥ (n+1)$^2$ ≥ 2$^n$ ≥ n$^2$*". You already made a mistake in here. Look at the first inequality. That is supposed to be the thing that you are going to prove. What you did, you assumed it. Did you see?

Comment: Sigh. Yes I did and I knew I was jumping the gun but for lack of any other ideas went ahead and did it anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Observe the following:

$$\begin{align}
n\geq 4&\implies n^2\geq 4n\\
&\implies n^2\geq 2n+2n\\
&\implies n^2> 2n+1.
\end{align}$$
$P(n)$ is assumed to be true and so, $$2^n\geq n^2$$ and so multiplying by $2$ to both sides, we get
$$2^{n+1}\geq 2n^2.$$
Thus, if $n\geq 4$ we get

$$\begin{align}
2^{n+1}&\geq 2n^2\\
&=n^2+n^2\\
&>n^2+(2n+1)\\
&=(n+1)^2
\end{align}$$
This means that $P(n+1)$ is also true.

Comment: These proofs can be so clever! I guess my question is next whether or not what I have done so far in my proof is correct, and if not, if I can alter it slightly to make it so. I am trying to develop an intuition in which to approach problems like this.

Comment: @agra94 Okay I understand. So this is just a formal proof that I know. Let me analyze your proof. wait for a moment.--)

Comment: Thanks again! I guess my question is now whether or not you have any tips for approaching induction. I feel like I always get kind of lost and don't realize the subtleties. I'm not sure if that's something you can really answer or if the answer is really just practice.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** For $n\ge 4$ you know that $(n+1)/n = 1 + 1/n \le 5/4$ so $(n+1)^2/n^2 \le 25/16 \le 2.$

Answer (score 0):

This is more a comment
than an answer,
but it does provide an answer.

In my answer to my own question,
I prove this:

If $n$ and $k$ are integers
and $k \ge 2$
and
$n \ge k^2+1$,
then
$2^n > n^k$.

Here it is:

[Prove that $n^k < 2^n$ for all large enough $n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/439026/prove-that-nk-2n-for-all-large-enough-n)